# Dynamic Class Variables - locals() vs __metaclass__

Tags: python, metaprogramming, metaclass

To create dynamic class variables you seem to have two options - using `locals()` or `__metaclass__`.  I am not a fan of assigning to `locals()` but it seems to work in a class definition and is more succinct than it's `__metaclass__` alternative.

Is it reliable to use `locals()` in this way?  What are the advantages/drawbacks for either solution?

```
meta_attrs = ["alpha", "beta", "gamma"]

class C(object):
    local_context = locals()
    for attr in meta_attrs:
        local_context[attr] = attr.upper()


class D(object):
    class __metaclass__(type):
        def __new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs):
            for attr in meta_attrs:
                attrs[attr] = attr.upper()
            return type.__new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print C.alpha, C.beta, C.gamma
    print D.alpha, D.beta, D.gamma
```

Comment: A third option is a class decorator or factory function that sets the attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__metaclass__` can be any callable:

```
class D(object):
    def __metaclass__(name, bases, dct):
        for attr in meta_attrs:  
            dct[attr] = attr.upper()
        return type(name, bases, dct)
```

This is almost as concise as the `locals()` method, and doesn't rely on CPython implementation details.

Comment: I'm accepting this one since it keeps the logic in the class, which is what I was going for.  Also, I learned something new.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned by kindall, a class decorator is a third option:

```
meta_attrs = ["alpha", "beta", "gamma"]

def decorate(klass):
    for attr in meta_attrs:
        setattr(klass, attr, attr.upper())
    return klass

@decorate
class C(object):
    pass
```

Here's a fourth option:

```
meta_attrs = ["alpha", "beta", "gamma"]

class C(object):
    pass

for attr in meta_attrs:
    setattr(C, attr, attr.upper())
```

I would go for a fifth option myself: Not having dynamic class attributes. I can't see the use case. If I really needed it, I'd probably use the fourth option, unless I needed it on more than one class, then I would use a decorator.

Metaclasses are often overly complicated, and the `locals()` hack really is just an ugly trick and should be avoided.